# Android Language selection

Tags: android, localization

I have code in where I choose language layouts and it didn't
work. We tested it with German (deutsch) which is ISO 3 code `deu` and for Spanish, which is `spa` -- it did not work either, or is the code different?

```
String locale = Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language().toString();
if (locale.equals("spa")) {
    setContentView(R.layout.es_pcversion);
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.pcversion);
}
```

Comment: what is the value of "locale", print it using Log.d(TAG, "locale: " + locale);

Comment: i am Java and Android newbie, could you please write the part of code ?

Comment: Why not use res/values-de and res/values-es?  Then Android will just use the correct values.

Comment: after String locale = Locale.get.... add Log.d("TAG", "locale: " + locale); and check the logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the values ​​files and translate your text inside.

For example, string.xml in values-es will be your text for Spanish language.

The gains folder containing your string.xml file, is your default language.

More information here :
[Supporting Different Languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

Comment: And please is there any way how to extract all hardcoded text to strings ? i have thousands lines of xml code with hardcoded text :D

Comment: Sorry, I do not think it's possible. It is a good practice has put in place early in the project.